How can I get the value of indicator arrow in MQL4
MQL4 has this setindexarrow
https://docs.mql4.com/customind/setindexarrow
But how can I know its value I can't see any way with iCustom for an .ex4 (I don't have source code). I tried all 8 buffers (since it's the max on MQL4) and I can't get anything ressembling arrow code.
Is it even possible ?

Do you want to know its value retrieving it in a chart or in order to set it in a chart?

I want retrieving
